# Como puedo arreglar en el header el cambio de login a logout y vicerversa en angular?

Tags: html, html5, angular, typescript, headers

Buenas tardes en el día de hoy me encuentro haciendo una autenticación de un usuario y aquí tengo un problema y es que al hacer clic en login o logout no me está cambiando la etiqueta  o link a login o logout.Me toca hacer doble clic para qué cambie y otro click mas para que ejecute la accion y quiero que esto no pase, como puedo arreglar esto?.

En la parte del codigo se encuentra el componente y html del login, en el header lo mismo y el authenticacion services los metodos que se usan para hacer autenticaciones y verificaciones. Si alguien me podria ayudar en resolver esto estaria agredecido

este es mi componente header

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(
    private authenthication: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  verifyLooged() {
    if (this.authenthication.verifyLooged()) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authenthication.logout();
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

este es mi html del header

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" routerLink="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/signup">Singup</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" (click)="verifyLooged()" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="onLogout()">LogOut</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

authenticacion services

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ConfigurationService } from './configuration.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../shared/components/header/header.component';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    Accept: '*/*',
  }),
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private URL_BASE: string;

  constructor(
    private configuration: ConfigurationService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.URL_BASE = this.configuration.getUrlBase();
  }

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  };

  singup(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.URL_BASE + 'signup', data);
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<> {
    const user: any = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    return this.http
      .post<>(
        this.URL_BASE + 'login',
        JSON.stringify(user),
        this.httpOptions
      )
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          this.authSuccess(res.access_token);
          return res;
        })
      );
  }

  authSuccess(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  getToken(): string | null {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    this.router.navigate(["login"]);
  }

  verifyLooged(): boolean{
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    //return token ? true : false;
    return !!token;
  }
}
```

componente login

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  mensaje!: string;
  form: any = {
    email: null,
    password: null,
  };
  //isLoggedIn = false;
  isLoginFailed = false;

  constructor(
    private authenthication: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // if (this.authenthication.verifyLooged()) {
    //   //this.isLoggedIn = true;
    //   this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
    // }
  }

  submit(): void {
    const { email, password } = this.form;

    this.authenthication.login(email, password).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        //console.log(data);
        this.mensaje = 'Datos Correctos';
        this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err.error.message);
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
        this.mensaje = 'Datos Incorrectos';
      },
    });
  }
}
```

html del login

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && submit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="email" required
            [(ngModel)]="form.email" #email="ngModel" aria-describedby="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" [(ngModel)]="form.password"
            minlength="8" #password="ngModel" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<div *ngIf="mensaje">{{mensaje}}</div>
```

esto pasa cuando me autentico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se puede observar que no cambia la etiqueta login, pero si le doy click de nuevo cambia, y si le vuelvo dar click me desloguea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo hay una mala detección del cambio de estado por eso no está cambiando la etiqueta o link a login cuando así debería ser. Para detección del cambio de estado de autenticación del usuario

podes usar BehaviorSubject [teoria](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/angular/angular-behaviorsubject/) definido en el servicio como

> > isLoginSubject este es un Observable y un Observer  tendrá un valor
> > booleano inicial de acuerdo a si existe en  el LocalStorage el token
> > mediante  hasToken() en el servicio retornamos su parte Observable
>
> mediante isLoggedIn Detectamos el cambio de estado en el header
> el async pipe  lo utilizamos en la vista
> para subscribimos

```
// services
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ConfigurationService } from './configuration.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../shared/components/header/header.component';

import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";

isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasToken());

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    Accept: '*/*',
  }),
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private URL_BASE: string;

  constructor(
    private configuration: ConfigurationService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.URL_BASE = this.configuration.getUrlBase();
  }

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  };
  
  
  private hasToken() : boolean {
    return !!localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  singup(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.URL_BASE + 'signup', data);
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<Presocloud> {
    const user: any = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    return this.http
      .post<Presocloud>(
        this.URL_BASE + 'login',
        JSON.stringify(user),
        this.httpOptions
      )
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          this.authSuccess(res.access_token);
          return res;
        })
      );
  }
  
  isLoggedIn() : Observable<boolean> {
 return this.isLoginSubject.asObservable();
}

  authSuccess(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
     this.isLoginSubject.next(true);
  }

  getToken(): string | null {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    this.isLoginSubject.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(["login"]);
  }

  
}
//header
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
   isLoggedIn : Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private authenthication: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) { this.isLoggedIn = authService.isLoggedIn();}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  verifyLooged() {
this.isLoggedInO.subscribe(bole=>{if(bole ==true) this.router.navigateByUrl('home'); })
```

}
}

```
  onLogout() {
    this.authenthication.logout();
    
  }
}
 // html header
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" routerLink="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/signup">Singup</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link"  *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async)" (click)="verifyLooged()" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)" (click)="onLogout()">LogOut</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Como el formulario sera de un usuario prefiero

```
usuario: any = {
    email: null,
    password: null,
  };
```

tambien en el evento submit enviar al formulario

```
onSubmit(form:any): void {....}
```

Con las modificaciones y teniendo en cuenta este tipo de errores para acceder
a valores requeridos
Property 'required' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['required'].

```
<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" [(ngModel)]="usuario.email" #email="ngModel"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && email.invalid }" email required>

        <div *ngIf="f.submitted &&  email.invalid " class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="email.errors?.['required']">Email is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="email.errors?.['email']">Must be a valid email address</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" #password="ngModel" class="form-control"
            [(ngModel)]="usuario.password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && password.invalid }" minlength="8"
            required>
        <div *ngIf="f.submitted && password.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="password.errors?.['required']">Password is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="password.errors?.['minlength']">Password should be at least 8 characters long</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>


usuario: any = {
    email: null,
    password: null,
  };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onSubmit(form:any): void {
    const { email, password } = this.usuario;
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
    console.log('Form value',form.value);
  }
```

Comment: Tengo un error es en la parte de verifyLooged para ser especificos esta parte: this.isLoginSubject.next(true); :this.isLoginSubject.next(false);  me dice "Unreachable Code Detected"

Comment: si  no lo vi porque en realidad no me parece que se requiera () de esa forma .  Lo llamas desde Head  y como el Observable isLoggedIn tiene un valor booleano  lo podes comparar dentro del metodo verifyLooged  el valor te lo envía el metodo isLoggedIn(), lo edito

Comment: cualquier cosa decime si no te funciona la edicion

Comment: Ya me funciono muchisimas gracias :), lo unico que me toco modificar fue en  verifyLooged() { en el header component fue quitar this.router.navigateByUrl('home'); ya que no me dejaba entrar al login.

Comment: Con este login tengo otro problema y es que le estoy intentando agregar validaciones de los inputs email y password de este formulario, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, ya que si agrego [class]="isValidField('email')" y formControlName="email" me aparecen errores, no sé si de pronto puedas revisarlo y aconsejarme que hacer, he revisado muchos videos, pero no me sirven me aparecen muchos errores. Este es link:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/544106/como-podria-arreglar-las-validaciones-de-los-inputs-email-y-password-de-este-for   Estaria muy agradecido si me ayudaras, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Si intento ayudarte mañana lo miro y te contesto en una primera mirada trata de usar formularios reactivos solamente no una mezcla mañana agrego validaciones s con formularios reactivos Te dejo un link para que lo intestes solo https://academia-binaria.com/formularios-reactivos-con-Angular/

Comment: Lo intenté hacer con formulario reactivos, pero confundió y me salió muchos errores, igual si mañana lo puedes revisar y ayudar a corregir, estaría muy agradecido, muchas gracias, es que todavia soy muy novato en esto de angular

Comment: subi el código para que te funcione con templete driven usando ngClass y bootstrap  particularmente uso reactivos y angular material pero para no contestarte con otro método lo corregí con el que subiste lo probe y funciona  podes ver teoría en https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: vos sos un crack enserio, muchas gracias ya lo probe y funciona correctamente, gracias :)

Comment: que me recomiendas estudiar para mejorar en angular?

Comment: te dejo un link de libro desde mi drive el código lo podes encontrar en github buscando por el nombre del libro........https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lH8Vmj69SWBF1wsafEChigBr9aSBOY1W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: muchas gracias :)

Comment: @JuanFelipeJimenezPacheco debe ser el autor de la respuesta quien edite su código. Indicale a través de un comentario cuál es el problema en cuestión que por eso viste la necesidad de editar su código, para que él lo corrija (si lo considera).