# Error con paginator en angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

El problema que tengo es que el paginador no puedo hacerlo funcionar ya que marca este error:

*ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.*

Lo que estoy haciendo es que primero con un campo select en html seleccione la opción y este al marcar la opción deseada, de click en un botón y despliegue la tabla, cosa que si hace pero al tratar de paginar los datos este me genera el error anterior.

**HTML**

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" color="accent">
          <mat-select formControlName="Cliente" placeholder="Cliente" ngModel required (ngModelChange)="clienteSeleccionado(Busqueda.value.Cliente)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let listaCliente of ListadoClientes" [value]="listaCliente.cliente">
              {{ listaCliente.cliente }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div>
          <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="primary"
                  matTooltip="Mostar Por Cliente">
            <mat-icon>manage_search</mat-icon> Buscar Registros
          </button>
        </div>
```

En la parte de evaluar que registro se hizo es este:

```
clienteSeleccionado(cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
  }
```

En el botón, para hacer el registro lo hice así:

```
submit() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.PTService.ListadoPorCliente(this.cliente).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.ValorValidacion = "SI";
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<datosCliente>(data);
          this.selection = new SelectionModel<datosCliente>(true, []);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          return resolve(data)
        },
        (err) => reject(),
        () => console.log('Datos entregados')
      )
    })
  }
```

Lo raro es que si responde y me pinta los datos en la tabla, el inconveniente es que da error la linea `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` , he tratado de basarme en este  [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-pagination-with-row-chkbox-print-slected?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-task.html,app%2Ftable-pagination-task.ts) pero veo que el paginado de datos lo ingresa así

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Pero yo donde lo ingreso es donde hago la búsqueda y este me retorna null.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Realice los siguientes cambios;

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<datosCliente> = new MatTableDataSource([]);
  selection: SelectionModel<datosCliente> = new SelectionModel<datosCliente>(true, []);
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

Y en donde hago la busqueda asi:

```
this.PTService.ListadoPorCliente(this.cliente).subscribe(res => {
      this.ValorValidacion = "SI";
      //console.log(res)
      this.datosResultados = res;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      
    });
```

Pero sigue sin resolverse el que el paginador reconozca la longitud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static = true. Access in ngOnInit

> Static = false. Access in
> ngAfterViewInit

puede solucionarse usando
ngAfterViewInit()  Se ejecuta cuando la vista del componente se ha inicializado por completo. Este método se inicializa después de que Angular ha inicializado la vista del componente y las vistas secundarias. Se llama después de ngAfterContentChecked.
Cuando static se establece en false, solo está disponible durante el enlace del ciclo de vida ngAfterViewInit
Si usas un  ChildComponent y está oculto o cargado dinámicamente de alguna manera a través del enlace de componentes (ya sea con enlace de propiedad o una llamada API), entonces * establecer static en false. Si Si  ChildComponent  siempre está disponible en la página y nunca está oculto. Entonces  usar  static false o static true

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="1" [pageSizeOptions]="[1,2]"></mat-paginator>



@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static:false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Comment: Sabes aun aplicando eso me marcaba error, ya que ocultaba la tabla y al presionar el botón este mostraba la tabla y los datos es por eso que dejaba esto **this.ValorValidacion = "SI";** y la ocultaba asi en el html `<div   *ngIf=" this.ValorValidacion === 'SI'">...</div>`

Comment: vi que usas  una promesa y dentro lo que parece un  llamada a la Api la cual consumís con subscribe siempre uso observables con angular proba convertir la promesa en un observable mediante from https://trungk18.com/experience/convert-promise-to-observable/ .....y tambien ValorValidation :BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null).......https://dev.to/sabrinasuarezarrieta/little-example-on-how-to-use-behaviorsubject-observable-in-angular-6ec

Comment: Para la detección del cambio mediante BehaviorSubject https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/544071/25463

Comment: *ngIf="!(ValorValidation  | async)"---> en el ejemplo veras como  recibir al BehaviorSubject como un Observable y subscribirse a su cambio en la vista