# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un suscribe de forma inmediata en TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, promesas, callback, javascript-metodo

Los datos llegan correctamente a **data** y hace la asignación al **carrito**, pero fuera de este método no puedo acceder al valor de **carrito**

```
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/service/api.service';

export class FormulariosComponent implements OnInit {

  carrito: Array<any> = []

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
            this.api.disparador.subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data);
              this.carrito = Object.values(data)
              console.log(this.carrito); //Aqui si imprime el valor correctamente
            })
          }
}
```

Este es mi servicio, la data me llega desde otro componente

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
export class ApiService {

  @Output() disparador: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  }
```

Aqui envio la data

```
export class PagosComponent implements OnInit {

 public carrito: any[] = [];
 
 constructor(private api: ApiService) { }
 convertir() {
    this.api.disparador.emit(this.carrito)
  }
}
```

Comment: Respuesta corta: *no se puede*. Saludos

Comment: necesito obtener el valor de this.carrito fuera del método suscribe, ya que no lo puedo mostrar en el html ni en otro metodo

Comment: podes hacerlo suscribiéndote mediante la libreria rxjs para aplicarlo Tenes esta explicación a una pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/544071/25463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El servicio se ocupara del BehaviorSubject es un sujeto que emite  el
> último valor emitido por la fuente Observable mediante el método
> next()   Un subject es un observer y un observable al mismo tiempo
> Subject como observable: dado un subject, es posible suscribirse a él
> proporcionando   un observer que comenzará a recibir valores. Subject
> como observer: es un objeto con los métodos ya conocidos:

```
next(valor), error(e) y complete().
```

Si queremos alimentar al Subject

> con un nuevo valor,  usamos next(valor) y se enviará a los observers
> que estén suscritos

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
 
export interface Carrito {
  id: any;
  value: string;
}

export class CarritoService {

  private carrito = new BehaviorSubject<Carrito[]>([{id:0,value:''}]);
 
 currentCarrito$ = this.carrito.asObservable();
 
  
 
  constructor() {}
 
  changeCarrito(carrito: Carrito[]) 
  // emitimos el ultimo valor
    this.carrito.next(carrito)
  }

}

import { ApiService } from 'src/app/service/api.service';

export class FormulariosComponent implements OnInit {

  carrito: Array<any> = []

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void 
 
            this.api.currentCarrito$.subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data);
              this.carrito = data;
              
              console.log(this.carrito); 
            })
          }
}
// pagos componente emite el ultimo valor del carrito mediente changeCarrito()

export class PagosComponent implements OnInit {

 public carrito: any[] = [];
 
 constructor(private api: ApiService) { }
 convertir() {
     export class PagosComponent implements OnInit {

 public carrito: any[] = [];
 
 constructor(private api: ApiService) { }


  convertir() {
this.api.changeCarrito(this.carrito)
      }
    }
      }
    }
```